# Universal Windows App Template Not installed

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2015, project

First of all let me make you clear you that, I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 update 1 and I am running on Windows 10 Pro.

As with update version of Visual studio I find inside Visual c#\Windows\Universal Tab that to install Universal Windows Tools.Also,I let you know that all other templates inside Visual C# Tab are installed and I can use them.

I have tried lot's of solutions to install them,still find the same.I have tried to modify VS from the installer package found under Program and Features in Control Panel.And also I have put for direct installation from that template Tab and selected all the necessary Tools from the Installation window.

What can I do next??[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution guys!!!

If you had upgraded your VS to VS update 1 or to any newer versions and i you get this error,then you need to try to uninstall VS completely and reinstall it and put tick on checkbox for 'Tools for Windows App and Windows 10 SDK' from the installation window.

Then your Project window gets the Universal Windows template installed...

Answer (score 1):

Open `control panel`->`programs & features`->`installed Programs`, select `Visual Studio 2015` and click on modify. Now select the `Universal Windows App Development Tools` and click ok to install them. Now you should see the entries in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ya,I have done that before,modified with the same as you mentioned and also checked on Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: Which Windows 10 Build do you use? The original 10240 from July or 10586 from November?

Answer (score 1):

A fresh install is required. So, if you are planning to Modify the setup, this will not work as it will not show the check box for Windows 10 SDK.

There are two ways:
1. Uninstall and reinstall the latest build -> Visual Studio Community 2015 - Update 3 as of now.

2. Install the preview edition, this requires 28GB, but you can customize your installation.
3. Install the Windows 10 sdk separately. Just go on http://dev.windows.com